# Recursive search doesn't work for grep on solaris

Tags: grep, solaris, recursive

On our Solaris server I'm finding that `grep -r` doesn't work, which is the usual way that I use `grep`. It seems that `egrep` has the same behavior.

Given that I have no control over the machine, is there a way to have `grep` perform a recursive search? Or do I need to pipe the output of `find` into `grep`?

Comment: What Solaris release are you using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Solaris, but if you're switching from GNU/linux to Solaris you'll find most of the commands will behave slightly different. The GNU version of Unix tools have additional features missing in "proprietary" Unixes.

You can download GNU grep(s) [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/grep/#TOCdownloading) then compile and install.

If you do have root access you might want to run
configure --prefix=/usr/local
Such that the utilities install into /usr/local

If you do not have root access you might want to run
configure --prefix=${HOME}
Such that the utilities install into your home directory

Comment: `--prefix=${HOME}}/.local` is probably more advisable... no need to clutter the home directory with `share` and `lib` folders

Comment: One man's cluttered is another man's organized

Comment: No doubt! Honestly, I'm protecting against the off-day when I say, "`share`? That's got to be a junk directory!" `rm -rf` Doh!

Answer (score 34):

If you want to use `find`, this would be the fastest way:

```
find . -type f -exec grep pattern {} +
```

However, Gnu grep is very likely already installed on your machine.

It is part of the default installation on Solaris 11 in `/usr/gnu/bin/grep`.
Same for Solaris 10 where you find it in `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep`.
On older releases, it might have been installed from sunfreeware or other repositories, check `/usr/local/bin/grep` and `/opt/csw/bin/grep` for common locations.

Comment: You could also make use of the `-name` option with `find`.

Comment: @sleepyweasel `-name` won't search inside the files but only search the file names which is not what the OP asks for.

Comment: This doesn't show name of the file, when it is grepped due to how grep works. Do you know how to make it so grep shows filename ONLY when it find the pattern in it? I'm on Solaris 11.3, if it matters.

Comment: @a_girl Can you clarify the issue you are experiencing? Unless there is a single file in the current directory, `grep` **does** show the name of the files where it finds the pattern in it.

Answer (score 7):

Use **ggrep** instead if it is installed.

E.g. Search for "mysearchstring" from the current directory down to all subdirectories (`-R`), and show the file name and path for matches (`-H`) and ignore binary files (`-I`). Don't forget the `*` on the end of the command.

```
/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -H -R -I "mysearchstring" *
```

ggrep is located in `/usr/sfw/bin`
You can add it to your profile with an EXPORT command so you can call it from the command line directly.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin
export PATH
```

Solaris version:  SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-13 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise

Comment: At least on my system, `ggrep` is indeed GNU grep. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Solaris grep does not have `-r` option.

You can use following command.

```
find . -type f | xargs grep 'sometext'
```

Comment: You don't need "control over the system" to compile GNU grep and install it somewhere under your home directory.

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks to point it out. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: This is very useful to find all files matching a name pattern and show results with the file. 
e.g.  

`find /opt/ -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs grep "start"`

Answer (score 3):

Download the standalone `ack` perl script from http://betterthangrep.com/, put it in your `$HOME/bin`, and learn to use it instead.  I find it is, as advertised, better than grep for many uses in my daily development work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need the GNU grep. Personally I do not miss the "-r" flag because you can do the same with a combination of `find` and `grep` but this reminds that having the GNU tools available on your Solaris box is what I would consider best practice. So here we go:

I wouldn't go about downloading source code from various places on the Internet and then building yourself. That is not necessary. If you simply want your Solaris to have the typical GNU tools available then do as follows:

If you are on **Solaris 10** you should get the Solaris 10 Companion Disk. This used to be distributed by Sun but it now lives [here](http://sunfreeware.com/companioncd.html). Personally I would make it a habbit always to install the contents of this disk or at least the most important GNU parts. Make it part of your JumpStart (or whatever you use) for new servers in your organisation !

If you are on **Solaris 11** life is a lot simpler. The GNU tools are typically installed by default but do not all of them get propagated into local zones. IFS, the packaging system on Solaris 11, makes your life a lot easier so you really should be moving to Solaris 11 (lots of other reasons as well). The list of packages that you should consider always to have available for any zone are these:

```
pkg://solaris/archiver/gnu-tar
pkg://solaris/developer/gnu-binutils
pkg://solaris/diagnostic/top
pkg://solaris/file/gnu-coreutils
pkg://solaris/file/gnu-findutils
pkg://solaris/text/gawk
pkg://solaris/text/gnu-diffutils
pkg://solaris/text/gnu-grep
pkg://solaris/text/gnu-sed
```

and if you use the host for development/build purpose you might want to add:

```
pkg://solaris/developer/build/gnu-make
pkg://solaris/developer/build/make
pkg://solaris/developer/gcc-45
pkg://solaris/system/header
pkg://solaris/developer/build/autoconf
pkg://solaris/developer/build/automake-110
```

Personally I would make the above (potentially less the dev tools) part of my company's default install for new servers / zones. Solaris sysadmins often insist on being different from Linux world but there's really no need to. Just do it and make it part of your default install. You won't regret it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you read the part where I said 'given that I have no control over the machine ...'  I'm sure this is useful information to someone, but it is hardly an answer to the question that I asked.

Comment: It is information for your sysadmin. He has given you a crippled machine IMHO. These things should be installed by default. But yes, you are right, the information was perhaps just as much intended for others that come to this place and read your question. Today you're missing GNU grep, tomorrow you'll be missing GNU tar, etc. You just don't know it yet.  :-)