# How do I redirect output from the find command (that uses grep) to a log file?

Tags: find, grep, solaris, io-redirection

Consider the code to search for all files containing the pattern "search string":

```
bash-3.2$ # The below find works fine..
bash-3.2$ find . -type f -exec grep -il "search string" {} \;
bash-3.2$ # But I am unable to redirect output to a log file..
bash-3.2$ find . -type f -exec grep -il "search string" {} \ > log.txt
find: incomplete statement
bash-3.2$
```

---

From the man pages for Solaris [find](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~arik/usail/man/solaris/find.1.html):

> ```
> -exec command   True if the executed command returns a  zero
>                 value  as  exit  status.   The end of command
>                 must be punctuated by an  escaped  semicolon.
>                 A  command  argument  {}  is  replaced by the
>                 current path name.
> ```

So it seems an escaped semicolon is compulsory. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: A quick workaround would be to start [`script`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) before running the find command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're deleting the `\;`. Just do this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il "search string" {} \; > log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally understood it.. its escaped and `grep -il "search string" {} \;` is passed as an argument to the `find` command, so that's why the above works..

Comment: @KentPawar well the `-exec` option of `find` will execute everything between `-exec` and `\;`. The `;` is escaped so it is not interpreted by the shell but passed to `find`. Mind you, you don't really _need_ the find, just do `grep -ril "search string" * > log.txt` to search through all files recursively.

Comment: okay. I had to go with find as the default grep on Solaris has no recursive capability. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/recursive-search-doesnt-work-for-grep-on-solaris

Comment: @KentPawar If you have bash4+, you can just use `grep **/* "search string" > log.txt` with the `globstar` shell option.

Comment: thanks @ChrisDown, currently I am using GNU bash version 3.2.51